# sqlite delete item

Tags: android, база-данных, sqlite, adapter

Ребята, у меня есть чекбокс по нажатию которого у меня добавляется айтем в БД. и по нажанию ещё раз на него должен удаляться...как мне это реализовать подскажите пожалуйста
если использовать "news" соответственно удаляется все таблица..а мне нужно по айдишке удалять

```
    public ContactViewHolder(View v, Context context, List<News> contactList, ArrayList<Boolean> clickItem) {
        super(v);

        this.context = context;
        this.contactList = contactList;
        this.clickItem = clickItem;
        tvTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        tvDescr = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvDescr);
        tvPrice = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvPrice);
        cardView = (CardView) v.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
        tvDatePublic = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvDatePublic);
        v.setOnClickListener(this);


        dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);

        cv = new ContentValues();


        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();


        btnFavorite = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.btnFavorite);
        btnFavorite.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        clickItem.remove(getAdapterPosition());
        clickItem.add(getAdapterPosition(), true);
        cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#BDBDBD"));
        context.startActivity(new Intent(context, BrowserActivity.class)
                .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                .putExtra("url", contactList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getUrl().toString())
                .putExtra("tile", contactList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getTitle().toString()));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        return false;
    }

    public String insert(News news) {

        cv.put("title", news.getTitle());
        cv.put("description", news.getDescription());
        cv.put("url", news.getUrl());
        cv.put("published", news.getPublished());
        cv.put("updated", news.getUpdated());
        cv.put("author", news.getAuthor());
        // cv.put("hours", news.getHours());
        //cv.put("descVisible", news.getDescVisible());

        long rowID = db.insert("news", null, cv);

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {


        if (isChecked) {


            this.insert(new News(contactList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getTitle(),
                    contactList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getDescription(),
                    contactList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getUrl(),
                    contactList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getPublished(),
                    contactList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getUpdated(),
                    contactList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getAuthor(),
                    111,
                    contactList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getDescVisible()));

            Toast.makeText(context, "Добавлено в избранные", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {

            db.delete("news",?? , null);

            Log.d("mLog", "deleted rows count = " + db);
            Toast.makeText(context, "Удалено из избранных", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }

    }

    class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public DBHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, "myNews", null, 1);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // Log.d(LOG_TAG, "--- onCreate database ---");
            db.execSQL("create table news ("
                    + "id integer primary key autoincrement,"
                    + "title text,"
                    + "description text,"
                    + "url text,"
                    + "published text,"
                    + "updated text,"
                    + "author text"
                    //+ "hours text,"
                    //+ "descVisible text"
                    + ");");
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {


        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Если внимательно читать [документацию](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#delete(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])) к методам, то можно заметить что в качестве второго параметра передается условие, по которому будет происходить удаление. Т.е. необходимо вызывать метод так:

```
db.delete("news","_id=" + id , null);
```

или так:

```
String[] whereArgs = new String[]{String.valueOf(id)};
db.delete("news","_id=?" , whereArgs);
```

Второй вариант предпочтительнее, т.к. исключает возможность использования sql инъекций.